# Which layout is suitable for table?

Tags: android

I would like to create custom layout for table dynamically in runtime. Here is what I want. 
        I don't know which layout is suitable for it (grid view or somethings). There is button and textview in each cell view. I have tried table layout. But it was not ok. I hope any idea for my table. Which layout is suitable?

I would like to show image for my table but I got this 'You need at least 10 reputation to post images'.
Thanks

Comment: A `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` might be suitable depending on exactly how you need it to look. If you have a link somewhere to the picture then someone with enough rep can edit and post it for you

Comment: here is my image https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9GZuKV7cDNsUzFmVWVoYVFDQnc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why was a table layout not ok? If you post what you had for that and what the problem is then we may be able to help fix it. You could use a `RelativeLayout` with nested `LinearLayouts` if table really won't work for you

Comment: Actually I cannot manage to do like this. If I add button into the table row, it will add another column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the whole `layout` for you but I can help get you started and you can make adjustments. A `TableLayout` should work but, to be honest, I don't like to use them because I feel I have more control using `RelativeLayout` when possible.

Your root `viewgroup` could be a `RelativeLayout` with 3 `LinearLayouts` nested inside them. Obviously use horizontal orientation for them (which is default for `LinearLayout`). Assign `id`'s to each and use the `RelativeLayout` properties

```
android:layout_below="@+id/idOfLLAbove";
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/idOfLLAbove";
```

to each. Inside each `LinearLayout` you have your `TextViews` or whatever they need to be. There are many different ways to accomplish it but something like this is probably what I would do

Also, you can give each `LinearLayout` a `weightSum` of 3 then each `View` inside each `LinearLayout` a `weight` of 1 so that they all line up. You may need to add/adjust properties to these `Layouts` depending on your exact needs but this should be able to get you started. Hope it helps

Comment: Hmmm; I never heard of "weightSum", but what I do sometimes is use linear layouts, give each child a width of 0dp and a weight of 1. This spaces them evenly across the linearLayout without regard to content. You can get other distributions with different weights. This works vertically too, of course.

Comment: Yes. I can layout with tablelayout. But there are two ui widgets: button and textview in the note column. The all of table columns are generated dynamically in runtime from db. If there is no note for this column in db, there is no button for it.

Comment: @EdwardFalk `weightSum` allows to specify a total of what the children should equal then you can disperse them as needed if you don't want them all the same. Say some of 5 with 3 children giving 1 1 3 so the last `View` takes up more room. And yes, still need to set `width="0dp"` if horizontal orientation

Comment: @user1156041 did you try something like what I suggested? This will give you more flexibility

Comment: Thank for ur answers. I choose the table layout. And I add the linear layout into the cell view. It's fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

use The tablelayout for making an table

read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

example of tableleayout http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/